# Where is bundelconfig.json executed?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

TLDR:

Q1. How is the `bundleconfig.json` file executed? What calls this on every build?

Q2. To get rid of this bundling & minification is it enough to remove the `bundleconfig.json` file or are there other references in the project that I should remove to completely remove it?

I have started using ASP.net MVC Core 2 with Visual Studio Code. I created a new project which created the official template file structure.

A `bundleconfig.json` file has been created at the root of the project which is responsible for bundling (and minifying) CSS/JS files etc. This `bundleconfig.json` file gets executed on every build automatically.

(I want to use Gulp for this instead as then I can do all build tasks in a single file instead of having to maintain two). I have seen that it's possible to combine both but I would prefer just Gulp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bundleconfig.json` is processed automatically by the `BuildBundlerMinifier` package during the build.

To remove this functionality:

1. Remove the `bundleconfig.json` from the project
2. Delete the following line from your project's `.csproj` file:

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="x.x.xxx" />
   ```

Comment: My initial thought was to remove it from the '.csproj' file however I do not have anything related to it in there. : <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: If it isn't referenced than it isn't actually processing the file. Several templates have/had a bug where the template included a `bundleconfig.json` and the bundled output file but not a reference to the `BuildBundlerMinifier`.

Comment: That makes sense, I just tested this and it looks like the `bundeconfig.json` indeed does not run on build without the reference in the .csproj file.